# Anaconda 3 Jupyter: jsonschema installed but says must install

Tags: anaconda, jsonschema

Running "jupyter notebook" from the Anaconda 3 command prompt generates this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jsonschema_*init*_.py", line 31, in 
from importlib import metadata
ImportError: cannot import name 'metadata' from 'importlib' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib_*init*_.py)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbformat\validator.py", line 12, in 
from jsonschema import ValidationError
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jsonschema_*init*_.py", line 33, in 
import importlib_metadata as metadata
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib_metadata'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 80, in 
from .services.contents.manager import ContentsManager
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\manager.py", line 17, in 
from nbformat import sign, validate as validate_nb, ValidationError
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbformat_*init*_.py", line 32, in 
from .validator import validate, ValidationError
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbformat\validator.py", line 23, in 
raise ImportError(str(e) + verbose_msg)
ImportError: No module named 'importlib_metadata'

```
Jupyter notebook format depends on the jsonschema package:
    https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonschema
Please install it first.
```

I have tried everything I have found in other threads here, using pip instead of conda install, etc.

For example, here is conda install ... apparently working fine and finding jsonschema already there as well:

(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install jsonschema
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

### Package Plan

environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
added / updated specs:
- jsonschema
The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:
jsonschema                                       anaconda --> pkgs/main
Proceed ([y]/n)? y
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done

Nothing that I do gets Jupyter Notebook to work in Anaconda 3.

Sorry about the corruption of the formatting of my note ... I do not understand why it smashed all the lines together into a huge block in this note when I entered it with separate lines.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

You must on Anaconda Prompt, do :

```
conda install jsonschema==3.0.2
```